# 10061 WSA E ConnRefused: The Teradata server is not accepting connections

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have installed Teradata Vantage Express (VMware / VirtualBox) 16.20 version

Teradata Tools and Utilities - Windows Installation Package 15.00 version

Teradata server is started successfully as:

```
Teradata Database Initiator service is starting...
Teradata Database Initiator service started successfully.
```

Have setup odbc connection with IP: **127.0.0.1**

But Teradata SQL Assistant is showing error message as

```
10061 WSA E ConnRefused: The Teradata server is not accepting connections
```

OS : Windows 64bit

ifconfig screenshot:
[ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa6Sq.png)

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost, i.e. your Windows system. But Teradata is running on VMWare, check the VM's IP-address and use this instead.

Comment: @dnoeth added a screenshot of ifconfig result in my post could you tell me what ipaddress i need to use?

Comment: So `eth0` did not obtain an IP address when the VM booted. Try `ifdown eth0` followed by `ifup eth0` and see if that gets you an IP.

Comment: @Fred Sharing the output  ```TDExpress1620_Sles11:~/Desktop # ifdown eth0
    eth0      device: VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller (rev 01)```  ,
```TDExpress1620_Sles11:~/Desktop # ifup eth0
    eth0      device: VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller (rev 01)
Starting DHCP4 client on eth0. . . . . . . .  
    eth0      DHCP4 continues in background```

Comment: Is the output from ifconfig any different after running ifdown/ifup?

Comment: @Andrew no its the same, how can I get the ipaddress any other ways?

Comment: I gave ```eth0 inet6 addr```  and its working, Teradata Sql assistant is connecting to odbc connection  created, i am able to see default database and tables